# Evaluating a finite double product with unknown, summed pairs of complex roots of $x^7-7$.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, products

Let $r_i$ (for $i = 1$, $2$, $\dots$, $7$) be distinct roots in $\mathbb C$ of the polynomial $f(x) = x^7 - 7$ and let $$M = \prod_{1\leq i < j \leq 7} (r_i + r_j)$$
The problem is to compute the value of $M^2$.

---

Given the above distinct roots, we can rewrite the polynomial by
$$\prod_{i=1}^7(x-r_i) = x^7 - 7$$
Define $g(x) = - f(-x)$ so that
$$g(x) = \prod_{i=1}^7(x+r_i) = x^7 + 7$$
Clearly, $g(0) = 7$ implies $\prod\limits_{i=1}^7 r_i = 7$. There has to be a way to use this fact to obtain $M$, but I don't know what further must be done. The correct answer is supposed to be $M^2  = 7^6$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\displaystyle
\;M^2 = \prod_{1 \le i \ne j \le 7} (r_i+r_j)=\frac{1}{\prod_{1 \le i \le 7}(r_i+r_i)} \prod_{1\le i,j \le 7} (r_i+r_j) = \frac{1}{2^7 \cdot 7} \prod_{1 \le i \le 7} g(r_i)\,$.

Comment: I don't understand the equation after the 2nd equal sign. Shouldn't that just evaluate to $1$ rather than $M^2$?

Comment: @Dee The LHS of the 2nd equal sign is the product of $(r_i+r_j)$ for $i \ne j$. The RHS is the same product written as the product of *all* pairs $(r_i+r_j)$ including those with $i=j$, from which the pairs $(r_i+r_i)$ corresponding to $i = j$ are removed by the division.

Comment: @Dee Suppose for example that $n=2$ instead of $=7$, then the first two equalities would be just:

$$
\big(\underbrace{(r_1+r_2)}_{=\,M}\big)^2 = (r_1+r_2)(r_2+r_1)=\frac{1}{(r_1+r_1)(r_2+r_2)} \cdot (r_1+r_1)(r_1+r_2)(r_2+r_1)(r_2+r_2)
$$